# How get DOM elements with a regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

For example, I want all the elements with an ID "hide_" + a value. This function must to return "hide_1" and "hide_30", etc, depending of the elements of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [dollar-dollar](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) syntax:

```
$$('a[id^="hide_"]')
```

should get you anchors whose IDs start with 'hide_'.

Most [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors) is supported from Prototype 1.5.1 +.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to assign common class to that elements and get them by

```
var elements = $$('.class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure DOM for general regex:

```
var all_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var results = [];
for (var i = all_tags.length-1; i >= 0; -- i)
  if (regex.test(all_tags[i].id))
    results.push(all_tags[i]);
return results;
```